# Drupal role does not appear in Views Filter

Tags: views

According to one post, I added Author uid in contextual filter but user role still does not appear in the filter. Any other lead help?

Answer (score 3):

By default, views of content only get access to the UID of the author. Add a relationship to the user to gain access to all the user-related fields, including your custom ones
[image]